# Как из children в expandableListView доставать изображения, если используется в адаптере одно и тоже ImageView?

Tags: java, android, listview, изображения, expandablelistview

В адаптере определен ImageView

```
img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.elvSecondLevelIcon);
```

Далее в адаптере в зависимости от child отображаются изображения.
В фрагменте, к которому применяется Adapter, при нажатии на child открывается диалоговое окно.

```
private void openDialog(HeroHistoryElvAdapter adapter, int groupPos, int childPos){
    SpellDialogFragment spell = new SpellDialogFragment();
    ***spellImage = view.findViewById(R.id.elvSecondLevelIcon);***
    spellImageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)spellImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("spellName", adapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos).toString());
    args.putString("heroName", heroName);
    args.putParcelable("imageBitmap",spellImageBitmap);
    args.putInt("childPos", childPos);
    spell.setArguments(args);
    spell.show(getFragmentManager(), "spell");
}
```

В Activity диалогового окна в зависимости от child меняются данные, но он все время использует изображение самого первого child, вне зависимости на какой child я жму. 
Layout для children:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/elvSecondLevelIcon"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/elvSecondLevelText"
    />
```

Как вытаскивать другие изображения из списка, чтобы при нажатии на определенный child я смог получить изображение именно этого child?

Comment: у вас есть структурированные данные для отображения в списке, очевидно эти данные связаны с определенным изображением и имеют позицию/индекс, по ним и получайте нужное изображение

Comment: @pavlofff Можете привести пример? Я новичок в программировании:)

Answer (score 0):

Когда в адаптере присваиваю картинку к ImageView, заодно присвоил и tag img.setTag("А1");. А в OpenDialog нашел картинку по тегу view.findViewWithTag